# HP has laptop limited performance on battery

Tags: laptop, performance, battery

If I unplug my laptop, it looses significant amount of performance - it is clearly visible even in switching windows, opening task manager, reading emails in outlook 365 desktop app etc... everything that is "instant" when plugged in, takes few seconds on battery.

To have also some exact numbers - this simple benchmark https://browserbench.org/Speedometer2.1/ scores over "200-280" plugged in, but only about "100-120" on battery.

I observed, that CPU won't go higher than 1,33 GHz on battery (less than half of standard frequency, compared to plugged in with "boost" goes up to 4 GHz). Maybe also other power management measures are in place (memory clock speed, ssd speed, GPU speed, ?? - I do not know).

I have tried everything I know to try to convince OS not to throttle performance on battery, but without any luck.

Do you know what else is there to try?

OS setup:

- Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings (only "balanced" plan exists and is active): change advanced power settings -> processor power management: minimum on battery 5%, minimum plugged in 5%, maximum on battery 100%, maximum plugged in 100%
- Settings -> System -> Power & battery -> power mode: Best performance
- "turn off power throttling" group policy and registry config is applied (both enabled) - https://www.nextofwindows.com/enable-or-disable-power-throttling-windows-11

Laptop specs:

- HP ProBook 650 G8
- CPU 11th gen Intel Core i7-1165G7 @ 2.8GHz
- RAM 32 GB
- BIOS HP T74 Ver. 01.14.00, 28. 6. 2023
- OS Windows 11 Pro

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/368781/how-to-enable-ultimate-performance-power-plan-in-windows-10/

Comment: https://tunecomp.net/add-high-performance-plan-windows-10-power-options/

Comment: Do you know if the CPU is a mobile CPU (less power hungry)?  Do you use Battery Threshold Management when plugged in?  Does the battery need to be reset?  (read about threshold management).  My Lenovo laptops (plural) on battery threshold management and with mobile CPU do not slow down measurably on battery.